# Is there a benefit to developing an iOS app against a docker instance?

Tags: ios, docker

Our backend is containerised with docker for use with minikube, I was wondering if as an iOS developer I can take advantage of this by running the backend locally on my laptop rather than having to communicate with a staging cloud based environment which can often be flaky.

Am I misunderstanding how this technology works, or would this be a viable and useful case for docker in iOS development, speeding up request and response times and allowing more control over the state of the backend I am building against?

Thanks for any clarity on this idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re explaining is possible and is something I do in my day job regularly so as to possibility, yes you can do this.

The question of whether this raises any benefit is broad and depends on every individuals needs. If you are finding that your cloud instance is extremely slow at the moment and you don’t have capacity to improve its performance, a locally run docker instance could very well help with this.

One thing to keep in mind though is that any changes you make to a local instance/server in order to make the app work as expected will need to be reflected into your production instance as soon as your app goes live to the public otherwise you will see undesired behaviour due to the app relying on non-existent server configs.

Comment: thanks, i plan to use it before it goes to QA who will test it against a mirror staging environment, so its good to know that its an option!